# how to have a translucent Activity with opaque and visible status bar

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

I have a activity with below style

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
```

but with this I'm also getting a transparent status bar. My requirement is I should get a opaque & visible status bar with the rest of the screen as translucent. I also added the below lines of code to the style

```
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/red</item>
  <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

But `fitsSystemWindows` is making the view break when opeing keyboard and also the animation is impacted. Also the activity is a `FlutterActivity` which already has below code overridden

```
override fun getTransparentMode(): TransparencyMode{
        return TransparencyMode.transparent
    }
```